# Why is prior to creation called holy?

Tags: midrash, creation, chol-hamoed, kedusha-holiness, mechilta

In Mechilta (to ex. 12.16), while discussing whether or not work is forbidden on chol hamoed, the time before and after the six days of creation are referred to as holy.

> ששת ימי בראשית יוכיחו שיש קדושה לפניהם ולאחריהם ומותרים במלאכה

Obviously after creation creation refers to the seventh day when God rested; very holy. But what is the reference to being holy about prior to the six days? Is this a specific reference to something, or shall I just learn from here that it was a holy time (that is, before time).

Comment: The Torah and angels existed before the creation. It might be referring to those

Comment: Perhaps *kedusha* means removal from the mundane (*chol*), so before and after the mundane exist is by definition sacred (*v'nisgav hashem l'vado*...).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The same text appears in [Chagigah 18a](https://www.sefaria.org/Chagigah.18a.6?lang=bi).

[Rashi there](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Chagigah.18a.6.1?lang=bi) commments:

> ששת ימי בראשית - ימי כל שבוע ושבוע בין שתי שבתות הן יושבין הרי קדושה לפניהן ולאחריהן:‏
>
> The six days of creation - Every set of weekdays are between two *shabbatot*, thus they have holiness before and after them.

So, according to Rashi it's simply a reference to the six weekdays in general, not the specific six days of creation.

Comment: Haha. I saw a reference to chagigah. Didn’t bother looking it up. +1 seems likely. זריזות מביאה לידי נקיות.